# jQuery script on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I use this HTML / jQuery Code to change the background onClick, but it does not work on mobile devices.

HTML:

```
    <div class="team white background content">
              <div class="overlay"></div>
              <div class="worker-background" style="background-image:url(img/worker.jpg);z-index:-5;" id="first-worker-background"></div>
              <div class="worker-background" style="background-image:url(img/background01.jpg);" id="second-worker-background"></div>
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="large-12 columns headline">
                      <h2>Lernen Sie unser Team kennen</h2>
                  </div>
              </div>
    <!-- SOME CONTENT -->
<span class="first-worker">First Worker</span>
<span class="second-worker">Second Worker</span>
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="large-12 columns team-select">
                      <span class="first-worker" style="background-image:url(img/worker_small.jpg)"><span class="worker-overlay" data-worker="Bernd Deus"></span></span>
                      <span class="second-worker" style="background-image:url(img/worker_small.jpg)"><span class="worker-overlay" data-worker="Michaela Deus"></span></span>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$( ".first-worker" ).click(function() {
    $( "#first-worker-background" ).fadeIn( "medium");
    $( ".first-worker-content" ).show();
    $( ".second-worker-content" ).hide();
});
$( ".second-worker" ).click(function() {
    $( "#first-worker-background" ).fadeOut( "medium");
    $( ".second-worker-content" ).show();
    $( ".first-worker-content" ).hide();
});
```

You can have a look on it [in the wild](http://deus.predatordesign.de/unternehmen.html) if you want!

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the script which stops from functioning:

```
var map_options = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    //----------^ Change it to Google or something.
    zoom: map_zoom,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false,
    styles: style,
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I get the same console-error "ReferenceError: Google is not defined".

Comment: @JonasLoerken What exactly should come there. That's the point where the problem comes up. That makes other scripts to fail.

Comment: @JonasLoerken Did you forget to include the Google Maps JS?

Comment: I fixed it! I changed the linked script https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API to http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API (http instead of https).

Comment: <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>

Comment: Exactly. Yeah, I am not sure if I helped you, but would you mind accepting the answer if you wish? `:P`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed id! Some mobile devices can't handle with

```
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size:cover;
```